# sql - get rows with first x field values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to get rows with, lets say, 3 first values for **type** field. For the following table called **items**

| id | name | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | banana | fruit |
| 2 | mango | fruit |
| 3 | car | toy |
| 4 | lion | animal |
| 5 | badger | animal |
| 6 | cupboard | furniture |
| 7 | shirt | cloth |

The result would be rows 1-5 (fruit, toy, animal).

I understand using sql `limit` like

```
select * from items
limit 3;
```

will not return rows with animals which I want to get. Is there any smooth way to achieve that?

Comment: Can you explain the logic for which results you're looking for in a little more detail? If id=6 had `type="animal"` too, would you want that one returned as well? What about if id=6 had `type="fruit"`?

Comment: I assume type value won't repeat after other stuff will apear. Therefore, there won't be `type="fruit"` with id=6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dense_rank()` after calculating the minimum id for each type:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by min_type_id) as seqnum
      from (select t.*, min(id) over (partition by type) as min_type_id
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3;
```

You could also use:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.type in (select t2.type
                 from t t2
                 group by t2.type
                 order by min(t2.id) asc
                 limit 3
                );
```

Comment: PostgreSQL 13 doesn't like the second one: error: column "t2.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select *
from items
where type in (
  select type 
  from (select type, min(id) as min_id from items group by type) x
  order by min_id
  limit 3  
)
```

Result:

```
 id  name    type   
 --- ------- ------ 
 1   banana  fruit  
 2   mango   fruit  
 3   car     toy    
 4   lion    animal 
 5   badger  animal
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/urCuJKTyGcXNhDsCaXeLxw/0).

Answer (score 0):

Use `LAG()` and `SUM()` window functions to assign groups to the types and select top 3 groups:

```
SELECT id, name, type
FROM (
  SELECT *, SUM(flag) OVER (ORDER BY id) grp
  FROM (
    SELECT *, (type <> LAG(type, 1, '') OVER (ORDER BY id))::int flag
    FROM items
  ) t
) t
WHERE grp <= 3
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c1403a38565371a0bf6e495c4b374b7e).